# Sequelize findAll not returning expected output on sequelize-mock

Tags: mysql, node.js, unit-testing, mocking, sequelize.js

I'm trying to do unit testing on my nodejs-express method with sequelize-mock.

**Controller**

```
const getDetailsByUserId = async (id) => {
        try {
            const userId = id ?? 0;
            const details = await Model.findAll(
                {
                    raw: true,
                    where: { user_id: userId  }
                }
            );
            
            if (details && details .length > 0) {
                return {
                    status: 200,
                    success: true,
                    message: 'details found.',
                    data: details 
                }
            }
    
            return {
                status: 404,
                success: false,
                message: 'details not found',
                data: []
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return {
                status: 500,
                success: false,
                message: error.message || "An error occurred while getting details.",
                data: null
            }
        }
    }
```

**Test**

```
jest.mock('../models/details', () => () => {
    const SequelizeMock = require("sequelize-mock");
    const dbMock = new SequelizeMock();
    return dbMock.define('users', [
        {
            id: 1,
            user_id: 123
            name: 'John Doe 1'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            user_id: 456
            name: 'John Doe 2'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            user_id: 789
            name: 'John Doe 3'
        }
    ]);
});

test('should return 404 and an empty array', async () => {
            const userId = 147;
            const details = await controller.getDetailsByUserId(userId);

            expect(details.status).toEqual(404);
        });
```

I always get the status of 200 instead of 404 here. I checked the returned data and it's returning the records of the defined mocked model.

**Actual Result:**

```
[
      fakeModelInstance {
        options: {
          timestamps: true,
          paranoid: undefined,
          createdAt: undefined,
          updatedAt: undefined,
          deletedAt: undefined,
          isNewRecord: true
        },
        _values: {
          '0': [Object],
          '1': [Object],
          '2': [Object],
          user_id: 147,
          id: 1,
          createdAt: 2021-09-18T00:55:25.976Z,
          updatedAt: 2021-09-18T00:55:25.976Z
        },
        dataValues: {
          '0': [Object],
          '1': [Object],
          '2': [Object],
          user_id: 147,
          id: 1,
          createdAt: 2021-09-18T00:55:25.976Z,
          updatedAt: 2021-09-18T00:55:25.976Z
        },
        hasPrimaryKeys: true,
        __validationErrors: []
      }
    ]
```

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Is there something I can do to get the expected result (empty array) for this scenario?
2. the `raw: true` seems to be not working when it is mocked. Is there a way could log the result on raw object?

**NOTE:** This only happens on the unit testing. When accessing the endpoint on postman it returns the expected result.

Comment: I am also getting same result, Is this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, `findAll()` will always return an array of a single result based on the where query in the options. This is why you will never get an empty array.

See more: https://sequelize-mock.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/model/#findalloptions-promisearrayinstance

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot to mention that my where clause is not present/available on the mocked db. As you can see on the Test part, I'm finding user id 147, but on the mocked db, I only have 123, 456 and 789. So I'm expecting the result of the test to fail/get an 404 status.

Answer (score 0):

Query results can be generated using query handlers. Use [$useHandler(handler) -> QueryInterface](https://sequelize-mock.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/queryinterface/#usehandlerhandler-queryinterface) to mock the query results and use the `queryOptions` to filter the results.

E.g.

`./models/details.js`:

```js
module.exports = {};
```

`./controller.js`:

```js
const Model = require('./models/details');

const getDetailsByUserId = async (id) => {
  const userId = id ?? 0;
  const details = await Model.findAll({
    raw: true,
    where: { user_id: userId },
  });

  if (details && details.length > 0) {
    return {
      status: 200,
      success: true,
      message: 'details found.',
      data: details,
    };
  }

  return {
    status: 404,
    success: false,
    message: 'details not found',
    data: [],
  };
};

module.exports = { getDetailsByUserId };
```

`./controller.test.js`:

```js
const controller = require('./controller');

jest.mock('./models/details', () => {
  const SequelizeMock = require('sequelize-mock');
  const dbMock = new SequelizeMock();
  const UserMock = dbMock.define('users');
  UserMock.$queryInterface.$useHandler((query, queryOptions) => {
    if (query === 'findAll') {
      if (queryOptions[0].where.user_id === 147) {
        return null;
      }
    }
  });
  return UserMock;
});

describe('69230853', () => {
  test('should return 404 and an empty array', async () => {
    const userId = 147;
    const details = await controller.getDetailsByUserId(userId);
    expect(details.status).toEqual(404);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  src/examples/stackoverflow/69230853/controller.test.js
  69230853
    ✓ should return 404 and an empty array (4ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |     87.5 |       50 |      100 |     87.5 |                   |
 controller.js |     87.5 |       50 |      100 |     87.5 |                11 |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.363s
```

package versions:

```json
"sequelize-mock": "^0.10.2",
"jest": "^29.5.0",
"sequelize": "^5.21.3",
```